# Distinguish multiple USB sound cards by USB port they're plugged in

Tags: perl, udev, raspbian, alsa

What I want is to be able to consistently tell apart multiple USB sound cards, identify them by the USB port they're plugged in and use that knowledge to play a sound on a speciffic sound card in my Java program.

So far I'm stuck on the first part - identify sound cards by the USB port.

First thing I did is to follow advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881729/java-sound-api-distinguish-multiple-equal-usb-sound-cards) and use the Udev rules to assign names to sound cards with the script from [this site](https://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev)

These are the Udev rules I added

```
KERNEL=="controlC[0-9]*", DRIVERS=="usb", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/alsa_name.pl %k", NAME="snd/%c{1}"
KERNEL=="hwC[D0-9]*", DRIVERS=="usb", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/alsa_name.pl %k", NAME="snd/%c{1}"
KERNEL=="midiC[D0-9]*", DRIVERS=="usb", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/alsa_name.pl %k", NAME="snd/%c{1}"
KERNEL=="pcmC[D0-9cp]*", DRIVERS=="usb", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/alsa_name.pl %k", NAME="snd/%c{1}"
```

and these are the contents of `alsa_name.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
#
my $alsaname = $ARGV[0]; #udev called us with this argument (%k)
my $physdevpath = $ENV{PHYSDEVPATH}; #udev put this in our environment
my $alsanum = "cucu";
#you can find the physdevpath of a device with "udevinfo -a -p $(udevinfo -q path -n /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c)"
#
#
$physdevpath =~ s/.*\/([^\/]*)/$1/; #eliminate until last slash (/)
$physdevpath =~ s/([^:]*):.*/$1/; #eliminate from colon (:) to end_of_line
#
if($physdevpath eq "1-1.3.1")
{
       $alsanum="11";
}
if($physdevpath eq "1-1.3.2")
{
       $alsanum="12";
}
if($physdevpath eq "1-1.3.3")
{
       $alsanum="13";
}
if($physdevpath eq "1-1.3.4")
{
       $alsanum="14";
}

#
if($alsanum ne "cucu")
{
       $alsaname=~ s/(.*)C([0-9]+)(.*)/$1C$alsanum$3/;
}
#
print $alsaname;
exit 0;
```

Now, when I plug my USB sound card and look at `/var/log/syslog` I see that it doesn't exactly work:

```
NAME="snd/%c{1}" ignored, kernel device nodes cannot be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:16
```

I tried to modify my Udev rules based on [this repository](https://github.com/dh1tw/remoteAudio/wiki/Persistent-USB-Mapping-of-Audio-devices-%28Linux%29) which provides an Udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="my_usb_audio_end"
ACTION!="add", GOTO="my_usb_audio_end"

DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="SPEAKER"
DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="HEADSET"

LABEL="my_usb_audio_end"
```

So I used my previous script and modified my rule:

```
KERNEL=="pcmC[D0-9cp]*", DRIVERS=="usb", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/alsa_name.pl %k", ATTR{id}="snd/%c{1}
```

but now `syslog` tells me:

```
error opening ATTR{some_very_long_id} for writing: Permission denied
```

I also tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394411/persistent-names-for-physical-usb-ports) and did

```
KERNEL=="pcmC[D0-9cp]*", DRIVERS=="usb", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/alsa_name.pl %k", SYMLINK+="snd/%c{1}
```

I don't see any errors in `syslog`, which I suppose is good, but when I list playback devices with `aplay -l`, all I see is

```
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and nothing changes, regardles of which USB port I plug it in. I also see no useful/distinguishable info in my Java program using `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()`

Is my approach correct and I'm just missing some detail, or this is completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @meuh's answer, I managed to get it to work, although a little differently that I originally planned.

Writing to `>/sys/devices/.../sound/card0/id` file was indeed the way to go, so I wrote a little bash script for that purpose

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find /sys/devices/ -name id | grep sound | grep usb)
do
    for fragment in $(echo $file | tr "/" "\n")
    do
        if [[ $fragment == *"1.2.1"* ]]
        then
            printf "%s" "EXT_B1" > "$file"
        fi
        if [[ $fragment == *"1.2.2"* ]]
        then
            printf "%s" "EXT_B2" > "$file"
        fi
        # etc
    done
done
```

This part - `for fragment in $(echo $file | tr "/" "\n")` - probably could have been done more elegantly, but I cannot just use a full file path, because I want to use *any* sound card and identify them only via USB port, but currently I only have one sound card so I can't check if that path changes for different models or vendors. Hence searching for the pattern `1.2.1` etc. describing speciffic port of USB hub connected to speciffic USB port of my device.

I haven't managed to run it using udev rules - apparently you need root access to write to  `/sys/devices/...` (which makes sense) but despite looking through several answers, I couldn't get it done - maybe because I'm running Raspbian Jessie on Raspberry Pi, maybe because I don't know much about Linux.

However, my use case doesn't necessarily require that script to be run upon connecting the device - simply running it on boot is sufficient, so the last thing necessary was to edit crontab using `sudo crontab -e` and add a line

```
@reboot /path/to/my/script.sh
```

And *voila*, I can get access a speciffic USB sound card in Java code using `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` and play sound using `AudioSystem.getClip(mixerInfo)`

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. There are a lot of things that can go wrong with udev.
The reason that udev rules with`NAME="..."` do not work anymore is that the kernel no longer allows you to rename devices in this way. The creation of symbolic links with `SYMLINK+=` work in general, but I don't know if alsa is interested in them.

So I think the likely correct solution is the advice given in your [linked article](https://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev) in the section titled *Identify two identical audio devices*.  Use a rule with `DEVPATH==` to match the device, and `ATTR{id}="ABC"` to give a unique name to that device that you will then find in `aplay -l` or `cat /proc/asound/cards`.

First, try the same thing manually. I don't have any usb sound cards but only a built-in device, so if I do:

```
find /sys/devices/ -name id | grep sound
```

it lists many items named "id", but some of these are directories, and the only *file* of interest is `/sys/devices/.../sound/card0/id`. If I `cat` this file it holds the name of the device ("PCH"). If I write a string into this pseudo-file it changes its name:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "%s" MYCARD >/sys/devices/.../sound/card0/id'
```

and this is seen in the output of `aplay -l`. This is what you are trying to do with udev; the sysfs pseudo-file `id` is an **attribute** of `card0`. So in udev, `ATTR{id}=` only works if you have matched in the right `/sys` directory, i.e. `/sys/devices/.../sound/card0` in my case. This is why the udev rule says `DEVPATH=="/sys/devices/.../sound/card?"` (the card number may change so it is replaced by the wild-card glob character "?").

For a more complete example see the above-mentioned section of the link which provides you a complete rules file `85-my-usb-audio.rules`.

Comment: Your tip to just write some ID to a speciffic file put me on the right track, although in the end I went with running script on startup instead of using udev rules.